# jQuery Multiple Animations with Different Duration, But runs simultaniously

Tags: jquery

How can I have 2 or more animations thats of different durations, but starts at the same time

when I do something like (for example)

```
$("#something").animate({opacity: 1}, 2500).animate({left: 1000}, 10000);
```

`#something` only starts moving right after opacity animation completes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Api Docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) you can set a property called `queue=false` to get the effect you want. So to revise the code:

```
$("#something")
.animate({opacity: 1}, {duration: 2500, queue: false})
.animate({left: 1000 +"px", queue: false}, {duration: 10000, queue: false});
```

I hope this does the trick :)

PS. One of the animations shouldn't have the `queue=false` property, so you could be able to chain other animation the object. In this case, you might wan't to skip the `queue=false` on the last animation, so chained animations only start AFTER the longest animations has ended. For example if you also want the height to animate after you current animation:

```
$("#something")
.animate({opacity: 1, queue: false}, {duration: 2500, queue: false})
.animate({left: 1000 +"px"}, {duration: 10000})
.animate({height: 500 +"px"}, {duration: 1000});
```

In that way the `height` will only animate after the `left` animation has ended.

Comment: The "queue" should be part of the second parameter, not the first.

Comment: Thank you @DemiImp - I have updated the example accordingly

Answer (score 4):

The jquery docs explain how to do this:  http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Effects#Simultaneous_Animations

I think this will do the trick, although you probably only need the queue: false property for one of the animations.

```
$("#something")
    .animate({opacity: 1}, {queue: false, duration: 2500})
    .animate({left: 1000}, {queue: false, duration: 10000});
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry misread your question

```
$("#something").animate({opacity: 1,left:1000}, 2500)
```

Comment: The question is how to make the left animation take a different amount of time, i.e. the full 10 seconds.

Comment: oh ok then dave has the answer for u :)